# iPad app startup image is truncated

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, png, splash-screen

I'm building an iPad app using Xcode 4.5.2, and recently the startup image has become truncated -- the bottom half of the image is missing, and in its place there's just a black background. The problem appears to be with the startup images (i.e. Default.png, Default-Portrait~ipad.png, and their @2x counterparts), although when I view them either in Xcode or in Preview they seem to be okay. The reason I think that the problem is with the images is that I also have a view controller that used the same Default.png image as in an image view, and the image appeared truncated there too; when I copied the image in Preview, saved it to a new file, and set the new file as the background image in my view controller, the problem disappeared.

Another important detail: the problem only appears on the device. Everything looks fine in the simulator. I suspected the @2x files, so I removed those from the project, but I *still* get a truncated startup image.

What's going on here? Seems like a case of file corruption, but I hate to dismiss it without knowing how it happened.

Comment: Have you tried removing the image from x-code (supporting files or resources folder) and adding it again?

Comment: Try reseting the simulator just to check if it happens the same then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the default images with a fresh copy resolved the immediate issue for me, and I'd recommend that anyone else experiencing similar symptoms try that. I'm still not clear on how the original images caused the problem, though.